# plsql append rows together from select statements (similar to rbind)

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Scores
( last_name VARCHAR2(40),
  score     number(10));
```

And I want to select the top and bottom scores into a table. The two queries would be:

```
select last_name,score, 'MAX' as Score_Type  from Test_Scores
where score = (select max(score) from Test_Scores)

-> Last_name | Score | Score_Type
       Smith |   15  |  Max

select last_name,score, 'MIN' as Score_Type  from Test_Scores
where score = (select min(score) from Test_Scores)

-> Last_name | Score | Score_Type
       Jones |   5   |  Min
```

How do I set these two rows together? In SAS I would use a set statement, and in R I would use rbind. Is there a pl sql equivalent (Oracle 11g)?

The final output would be:

```
Last_name | Score | Score_Type
    Smith |   15  |  Max
    Jones |   5   |  Min
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using plain SQL and a window (aka "analytic") function. There is no need for PL/SQL here (PL/SQL is *only* used for stored procedures)

```
select last_name, 
       score
from (
   select last_name, 
          score,
          dense_rank() over (order by score desc) as ranked_first,
          dense_rank() over (order by score asc) as ranked_last
   from test_scores
) 
where ranked_first = 1 
   or ranked_last = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, thats great. Out of interest is there a SQL equivalent of rBind or is it always the way that you need to just be creative with the select statement?

Comment: @Zfunk: sorry I have no idea what rBind is.

Comment: Long time ago I know but in case someone else comes across this like I did, the SQL command you are looking for is UNION.